# avoid Setting with copy warning

Tags: python, pandas

edit: thanks Wen, this is updated pending a delete.

Both of the below assignments produce the same SettingWithCopyWarning.

```
series = u[columns].copy() # this copy

for app in endog:
    min_nonzero = series[series[app] > 0].min()[0]

    series.loc[series[app] == 0, app] = min_nonzero - 0.00001 # works with this copy
    #series[app][series[app] == 0] = min_nonzero - 0.00001
```

The second one I get.. but the first, I've seen that form as an accepted answer to "how to avoid the SettingWithCopyWarning" questions here on stackoverflow. Why is it wrong? what do I need to do?

Comment: ,copy() add this

Comment: oooh! I get it..just before lol thank you.